# Directory.GetFiles returns unexpected results with SearchPattern

Tags: c#, .net, base-class-library, system.io.directory

I'm working on a batch program that process a big amount of files (more than 50 000 files) and I'm facing weird behavior with the `Directory.GetFiles` method.

In the process I move files that matches the following search pattern "*.pdf", and get the files thanks to the `Directory.GetFiles` method :
I was very surprised to see that sometimes I have .pdfa files moved.

So I've checked the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx) and it clearly states that if the search pattern contains an extension with 3 letters every files that have an extension that begins with the extension will be returned.

I've tested with a simple program and It does not behave like stated in the doc,  it only behaves like this in very rare occasion.

With this code :

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var directory = @"E:\Test\";
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.pdf");
    foreach(var file in files)
        Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

I have this result :

[image]

Do you have any explanation about this behavior ?

Comment: It is normal mishap.  Getting *really* long in the tooth, but file system volumes today still routinely have DOS 8.3 name support turned on.  So verylongname.pdfa gets turned into verylo~1.pdf and your search pattern will match it.  Post-filtering required.

Comment: As you can see in the result in the screenshot, IT DOES NOT. You can see in the screenshot that the .pdfa file IS NOT in the output.

Comment: As Hans explained, it will do it when there are alternate names for the file that only have a three-letter extension, as in MS-DOS compatible 8.3 names. In your example, the file obviously doesn't have a 8.3 name, so it isn't matched.

Comment: Dude, don't yell at me.  Type dir /x instead and yell at what you see.

Comment: I was not yelling at you, I'm sorry if you tought I was.
Here is an extract of the result : 
E:\Test>dir /X
 Répertoire de E:\Test

04/01/2017  13:15           706 333              349739_09000010.pdf
12/01/2017  13:47           370 971              349739_09000010.pdfa

Comment: Add it to the question rather than a comment. But in any case, it's obvious the files do not have 8.3 names - otherwise they would be shown :)

Comment: All right, found it, thanks to your help and the luaan help, I've understood that the 8.3 format is disabled on the drive I have tested my code on. Thanks a lot for your help ! :)

Answer (score 5):

This is the expected behavior of the GetFiles method and it's same on Windows as well, if you search in directory with ***.pdf*** it will pick files with extensions **.pdfa** or ***.pdfaaa**, you would need to put a `Where()` yourself like:

```
Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.pdf").Where(item => item.EndsWith(".pdf"));
```

As you can see that when we search in windows It is giving the same result as your code was giving:

[image]

For the reason of why the **GetFiles** is behaving that way [please have a look here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/152289/Directory-Get-Files-search-pattern-problem) and you might also want to look at [this post as well](http://graphicdna.blogspot.nl/2011/02/using-directoryinfo-to-getfiles-returns.html)

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot IT DOES NOT !! I DO NOT have the .pdfa file in the output

Comment: The whole point of the question is that it *doesn't* always do this. `*.pdf` will only match an extension that's exactly `pdf`, not `pdfa`. However, if you have a 8.3 name associated with that file, you *will* get the `.pdfa` file, because its 8.3 name only has an extension of `pdf`, not `pdfa`.

Comment: What do you mean with "if you have a 8.3 name associated with that file" I think that every file has a 8.3 name associated, I'm wrong ?

Comment: @PatriceVB If you have NTFS, it can be disabled (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/121007/how-to-disable-8.3-file-name-creation-on-ntfs-partitions). On other file systems, the rules may be completely different (CDs, FAT, network shares, ext...).

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @luaan and by @hans-passant (thanks a lot !) I do not found the file with the .pdfa extension, because the 8.3 format is disabled on my hard drive.

On a hard drive with the 8.3 format enabled, the method behaves like stated in the doc.

The GetFiles has a different behavior with the setting enabled or not.